# When greenplum gpss commit to kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka, greenplum

Im trying to use `gpss` (Greenplum Stream Server) for loading data from Kafka to GreenplumDB.

Main question is how\when `gpss` instance commit current writen offset to kafka?

Right now `gpss` instance does not commit any message to kafka but handle current offset in service table in GreenplumDB.
Expected behavior for me is:

0. With using given group.id  and topic (that mandatory in kafka and not mandatory in gpss settings - looks strange btw)
1. Start consuming data from kafka topic
2. Track higher offset by partition
3. Wait when COMMIT condition is occur (COMMIT is block of settings in gpss job config)
4. Write batch of data from kafka to external table using `gpfdist`
5. Commit max offset by partition to kafka
6. repeat

But right now its working without step n.5
Any one know why?

The second question is - does gpss use a group.id?
In gpss job config i found `PROPERTIES` block config that correspond to kafka consumer config properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gpss would commit consumed offset to Kafka if the 'group.id' is set in the yaml file since version 1.6.0. It only commited offset to the tracking table of Greenplum before.

Comment: Not try right now but its seems solution for me - bump version to 1.6.0. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

By default GPSS write committed offsets to tables in your schema. You can choose "consistency mode = strong" in your .cfg file to write committed offsets to Kafka too.

https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Greenplum-Streaming-Server/1.10/greenplum-streaming-server/kafka-about-offset-mgmt.html

like this:

COMMIT:
MINIMAL_INTERVAL: 5000
MAX_ROW: 500000
CONSISTENCY: strong
PROPERTIES:
group.id: gpss